# Trouble installing Ubuntu with USB on laptop

Tags: installation, kernel, live-usb

I have created a bootable USB stick using Universal USB Installer 1.9.0.9 and tried to boot from my USB on a laptop with a clean hard drive.  I keep getting the message

```
Could not find kernel image: vesamenu.c32.
```

I have found the file on the USB, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A few suggestions: 1. Make sure the iso you downloaded is not corrupt. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM 2. The process of making the USB bootable might have gone wrong. So try once more.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no universal panacea for USB install.

If you create a USB 'LiveCD' from within **Ubuntu**, it will nearly always work.  You only have to be concerned with disparity between the version of Ubuntu used to create and the version being installed.  This can cause issues similar to what you are experiencing.

You are far more likely to have issues with USB 'boot' and 'kernel', with a third-party USB creator application.

---

***Fail Safe Approach***

( until you have a nearby **Ubuntu 12.04** to use 'Startup Disk Creator'. )

Download the **.ISO** image, and burn to CD.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you make the ubuntu usb stick on an older version of ubuntu. You can usually just press tab and type one of the commands it lists to boot.