# Samsung ultrabook usb stick install of Ubuntu fails, keeps booting windows

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, usb, cd-image

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a Samsung ultrabook via a usb stick.

I've tried 12.04 both regular and alternate on 3 different USB sticks but not having success.

The laptop just keeps booting into windows.

I used unetbootin to create the USB image as this worked for when when doing a toshiba ultrabook installation.

I reset my Boot Menu to be

```
1 USB HDD
2 USB CD
3 USB FDD
4 SATA HDD SanDisk SSD u100 128GB
```

Then F10'd but no success, still boots windows.

I've tried changing `UEFI boot support` to be enabled and I've tried changing PXE OPROM to be enabled but neither has helped.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/181643/trouble-installing-ubuntu-with-usb-on-laptop

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question.  See my answer

Comment: In Series 9:

1. In BIOS set: USB HDD as the first option in Boot Priority
2. Change Fast Bio Mode to disabled.

If that doesn't work try other USB pen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ** -----> Found it! <----- **

The fix was pretty obsure and I had to test it out a bit to be sure.

Given how strange it was this may well help others who are stuck!

- Reboot with f2 pressed.
- Wait 10 seconds until you can use the left/right keys to change boot.
- change the boot order putting the USB items first (3 in my case). Use f5/f6 keys.

and then...

on the advanced tab settings...

- Change `Fast Bio Mode' to disabled.
- Change USB s3 wake-up to enabled.
- F10 to save and it will...
- boot into Ubuntu from the USB key.

This took me 2 days to find!

Comment: After that, changing usb port worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, and I solved it (searching for 3 hours) by disabeling the boot on the HDD with CTRL + 1 in the boot sequence !

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked by disabling the Secure Boot in the BIOS

Comment: Preventing the Windows reboot is attained "disabling the Secure Boot in the BIOS"

Answer (score 0):

following on from: [Trouble installing Ubuntu with USB on laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181643/trouble-installing-ubuntu-with-usb-on-laptop)

Create new USB Startup media using Ubuntu on your Toshiba.

Comment: I did this and it wasn't the fix.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was too brief.  The issue was **EITHER** (a.) *Needed better USB install media*; **OR** (b.) *Needed to manually force BIOS-boot to choose ONLY the correct device.*  ***Your method achieved a variant of (b.), by making boot-order (notoriously unreliable) work correctly.***